# Can't save Shared photos

Tags: facebook-messenger

There is an option on Facebook messenger that lets you view shared photos  I can't save any of them to gallery. After I long press on photo it opens but there is no options.

Answer (score 1):

Once the photo is open there should be three vertical dots in the bottom right corner (if you don't see them initially tap once on the image/screen). Tapping on the dots will open a menu that includes the save option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Settings within the Messenger app, then to Photos and Media and select "Save photos". After that, all photos will be saved automatically. This is the only way AFAIK.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want all photos to be downloaded

Comment: But maybe he does. We don't know. "Any" can be 1 photo or all of them. My answer gives the correct end result, as the OP asked. The process of how he wants it to work is not specified in the question and is probably  irrelevant for the problem.